# Export maps with image popups?

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to export a map from QGIS with popup images?

Within QGIS, I can create a point layer with popup images using the html maptips (using Nathan Woodrow's method https://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/html-map-tips-in-qgis/ ).

I would like to export a map to a common file type that preserves this functionality.

My end goal is to be able to share maps with a non-gis users who could view the photos.

I created something like this in a PDF file that used buttons, but it was pretty clunky, and wasn't as smooth as exporting from QGIS.  Each button had to be created individually, then the photo was pasted into it.

Comment: qgis2web https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/wiki